# android unresolved class error after choosing class suggestion found by android studio

Tags: android, android-manifest

I am having an unresolved class error in my manifest file and I do not quite understand why. If I try to refer to the class, Android Studio suggests me the correct class but when I select it it shows me unresolved class error. The class is inside of a base package inside of AndroidTest folder.

What could be the issue here? I read that I might be missing some line in my build.gradle file to include the corresponding classes inside of the build path, but I am not sure how to add this?

Android Manifest File, suggestion being made by Android Studio:

[image]

Android Manifest File, no class found error when adding suggestion to manifest file:

[image]

This is my current build.gradle file:

[image]

[image]